# SSPI unexpectedly authenticates for accounts with same passwords

Tags: kerberos, sspi, waffle

I have written a Java client and server (on Win7 hosts) communicating remotely with RMI. I want the Server to authenticate the Client user without the Client user needing to provide credentials (i.e. single sign on). In order to avail of Window's [SSPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/sspi), I am using the [Waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle) library.

- Server is running on **host1.dev.mydomain.com** with the service account **dev\svc_serviceaccount**
- I have added an SPN, **test/host1.dev.mydomain.com** for **dev\svc_serviceaccount**
- Client is running on **host2.dev.mydomain.com** as **dev\testuser** and is configure to use the SPN above
- Both Client and Server are configured to use the Kerberos (not Negotiate) SSPI provider

Everything works as expected, Server successfully authenticates the Client and with Wireshark I can see the Kerberos packets being sent between the Client and the Domain Controller.

Next, I change the Server to run as a different service account (**dev\svc_serviceaccount2**). There is no SPN for this service account. Client continues to run, configured with the original SPN. As expected, the Server now fails to authenticate the Client.

Finally, I change the password of **dev\serviceaccount2** to be the same as **dev\serviceaccount1** and run as per the failing scenario above. Except now the Server successfully authenticates the Client!!

I believe secret keys are derived from password hashes, but this still surprises me. Can anyone confirm if this is expected functionality from SSPI? I'm trying to determine if there is an issue with my code (or maybe Waffle). Or perhaps an environmental factor is causing this? Any help/explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Same password => same hash. The question is, how do you store these passwords??? You have a _single_ password **hard-coded** somewhere, not associated with the AD account it relates to?!?

Comment: Service accounts usually get random passwords, extracted via keytab files. And the keytab contains pairs of (login, password) values.

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide any explanation. You need to provide some code of how the client is requesting tickets (how it determines server SPN), how the server is actually validating tickets, potentially a sample kerb ticket sent between client/server, etc. The only notable thing here is svcaccount2 doesn't have an SPN, which means SSPI will attempt user-to-user kerberos auth.